# SQL Server 2008 compare two tables in same database and get column is changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I need to get the difference between two tables. 
I need to compare Product, Qty & price columns from two tables and say if its new record or I need to mention which column value is changed.

Example Table A

```
Product | Qty | Price | Comments

A          20    500     xyz
B          50    200     xyz
C          90    100     abc
```

Example Table B

```
Product | Qty | Price | Comments

A          20    500     sd
B          70    200     cv
C          90    200     wsd
D          50    500     xyz
```

Currently I am using Expect which gives all new / mismatched rows.

```
select Product,Qty,Price 
from TableB 
except 
select Product,Qty,Price 
from TableA

Product | Qty | Price 
B          70    200   
C          90    200   
D          50    500
```

But I need the result set like below

```
Product |  Result

B          Updated Qty
C          Updated Price
D          New
```

Comment: What would the result be if more than one column had been updated?

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for your comment. If more than one column is updated , I need to mention all column names that are updated. eg Updated Qty,Price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  b.Product,
        b.Qty,
        b.Price,
        Result = CASE WHEN a.product IS NULL THEN 'New'
                    ELSE 'Updated: ' + 
                        STUFF(  CASE WHEN a.Qty != b.Qty THEN ',Qty' ELSE '' END + 
                                CASE WHEN a.Price != b.Price THEN ',Price' ELSE '' END,
                            1, 1, '')
                END
FROM    TableB b    
        LEFT JOIN TableA a
            ON a.Product = b.Product
WHERE   a.Product IS NULL
OR      a.Qty != b.Qty
OR      a.Price != b.Price;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4b0/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Not the most concise approach for sure, but readable and probably efficient:

```
SELECT B.Product,
       Result = 'Updated Qty'
FROM TableB B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A
    ON B.Product = A.Product 
WHERE A.Product IS NOT NULL 
AND A.Qty <> B.Qty
AND A.Price = B.Price

UNION ALL

SELECT B.Product,
       Result = 'Updated Price'
FROM TableB B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A
    ON B.Product = A.Product 
WHERE A.Product IS NOT NULL 
AND A.Price <> B.Price
AND A.Qty = B.Qty

UNION ALL

SELECT B.Product,
       Result = 'Updated Qty and Price'
FROM TableB B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A
    ON B.Product = A.Product 
WHERE A.Product IS NOT NULL 
AND A.Price <> B.Price
AND A.Qty <> B.Qty

UNION ALL

SELECT B.Product,
       Result = 'New'
FROM TableB B 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA A
    ON B.Product = A.Product 
WHERE A.Product IS NULL
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87b4b/4/0)</kbd>

If you need to order the result you have to do that  in an outer query like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87b4b/6/0).